# App sometimes crashed on start

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

This sometimes occurs if you manually kill the app and start again.
It never happens when you startup via xCode.

As I understood App didn't have time to load.
*(failed to scene-create after 16.56s)*

Device: iPad2 iOS 8.3.4 / 9.0.2

Crash-log:

```
    Initialization of BASS Subsystem:
Oct 10 18:17:25 iPad WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull[994] <Warning>: ...Creating a BASS device...
Oct 10 18:17:26 iPad WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull[994] <Warning>: Level Manager: Found 2 stages with 89 levels...
Oct 10 18:17:26 iPad WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull[994] <Warning>: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EE265319-6E99-419D-A117-AE86C9303EB2/Documents/EleFun Games/Witches Legacy Slumbering Darkness CE/default/profiles\link_30845047142.upf
Oct 10 18:17:36 iPad WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull[994] <Warning>: Loading resources times: 0.0050 0.0000 0.0160 0.0050 0.1430 0.0390 0.0320 0.1650 0.0333; total: 0.438333
Oct 10 18:17:36 iPad WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull[994] <Warning>: loading 'data\ui\gui_loaded.xml' time: 0.033333
Oct 10 18:17:40 iPad WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull[994] <Warning>: Default datastore will be saved at /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EE265319-6E99-419D-A117-AE86C9303EB2/Library/Application Support/com_upsight/DefaultDataStore_v1_0.sqlite
Oct 10 18:17:40 iPad WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull[994] <Warning>: SDK Version: 4.0.2.+release.91a51d8
Oct 10 18:17:40 iPad SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: Forcing crash report of <FBApplicationProcess: 0x1848b670; WitchesLegacy5_; pid: 994> (reason: 1, description: com.bigfishgames.wlsdaapltabletful failed to scene-create after 16.56s (launch took 3.44s of total time limit 20.00s))
Oct 10 18:17:42 iPad ReportCrash[995] <Error>: assertion failed: 13G36: libsystem_trace.dylib + 15927 [E82A6F2D-873A-39AD-8014-EDEB52248157]: 0x0
Oct 10 18:17:42 iPad Unknown[995] <Error>: 
Oct 10 18:17:42 iPad ReportCrash[995] <Warning>: os_activity_diagnostic_for_pid() failed!
Oct 10 18:17:42 iPad SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: Finished crash reporting.
Oct 10 18:17:42 iPad com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.bigfishgames.wlsdaapltabletful[0x4d5a][994]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
Oct 10 18:17:42 iPad SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection invalid
Oct 10 18:17:42 iPad SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection invalid
Oct 10 18:17:42 iPad SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Oct 10 18:17:42 iPad SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.bigfishgames.wlsdaapltabletful[0x4d5a]' exited abnormally via signal.
Oct 10 18:17:42 iPad UserEventAgent[23] <Warning>: 1798929331965: id=com.bigfishgames.wlsdaapltabletful pid=994, state=0
Oct 10 18:17:43 iPad mediaserverd[42] <Notice>: '' com.bigfishgames.wlsdaapltabletful(pid = 994) setting DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None
Oct 10 18:17:43 iPad mediaserverd[42] <Notice>: '' (pid = 994) setting DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None
Oct 10 18:17:44 iPad ReportCrash[995] <Warning>: Report of type '109(109_WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull)' not saved because the limit of 25 logs has been reached
Oct 10 18:17:45 iPad ReportCrash[995] <Error>: Notice: This report is abbreviated for syslog inclusion because it could not be saved to disk.
    Symbolication may be possible by manually cleaning up and including the Binary Image section of a full report from this same device -- good luck!
Oct 10 18:17:45 iPad ReportCrash[995] <Error>: Process:             WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull [994]
    Path:                /var/containers/Bundle/Application/606E5E39-F345-46DD-B10F-BE93B2E88487/WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull.app/WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull
    OS Version:          iOS 9.3.5 (13G36)
Oct 10 18:17:45 iPad ReportCrash[995] <Error>: Exception Type:  00000020
    Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
    Exception Note:  SIMULATED (this is NOT a crash)
    Highlighted by Thread:  0
Oct 10 18:17:45 iPad ReportCrash[995] <Error>: Application Specific Information:
    com.bigfishgames.wlsdaapltabletful failed to scene-create after 16.56s (launch took 3.44s of total time limit 20.00s)

    Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 19.090 (user 19.090, system 0.000), 48% CPU 
    Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 11.878, 30% CPU
Oct 10 18:17:45 iPad ReportCrash[995] <Error>: Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x221a2998 0x2218e000 + 84376
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2224adec 0x22248000 + 11756
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2224bc98 0x22248000 + 15512
    3   Foundation                      0x22d27cb6 0x22c65000 + 797878
    4   WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x0024193c 0x57000 + 2009404
    5   WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x0024103e 0x57000 + 2007102
    6   WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x00280b50 0x57000 + 2267984
    7   WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x00280950 0x57000 + 2267472
    8   WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x00280be8 0x57000 + 2268136
    9   WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x00280328 0x57000 + 2265896
    10  WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x0027991e 0x57000 + 2238750
    11  WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x0027798e 0x57000 + 2230670
    12  WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x00277b3a 0x57000 + 2231098
    13  WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x00277054 0x57000 + 2228308
    14  WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x00260e2c 0x57000 + 2137644
    15  WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x00261556 0x57000 + 2139478
    16  CoreFoundation                  0x224c9734 0x2241e000 + 702260
    17  CoreFoundation                  0x224c913e 0x2241e000 + 700734
    18  CoreFoundation                  0x224c8f1c 0x2241e000 + 700188
    19  CoreFoundation                  0x2251fc6a 0x2241e000 + 1055850
    20  CoreFoundation                  0x22429082 0x2241e000 + 45186
    21  Foundation                      0x22c6a5de 0x22c65000 + 21982
    22  UIKit                           0x26d2f45a 0x26a7f000 + 2819162
    23  UIKit                           0x26d33284 0x26a7f000 + 2835076
    24  UIKit                           0x26d4783c 0x26a7f000 + 2918460
    25  UIKit                           0x26d307b2 0x26a7f000 + 2824114
    26  FrontBoardServices              0x23bbac06 0x23b96000 + 150534
    27  FrontBoardServices              0x23bbaab8 0x23b96000 + 150200
    28  FrontBoardServices              0x23bbadb8 0x23b96000 + 150968
    29  CoreFoundation                  0x224d9dfe 0x2241e000 + 769534
    30  CoreFoundation                  0x224d99ec 0x2241e000 + 768492
    31  CoreFoundation                  0x224d7d5a 0x2241e000 + 761178
    32  CoreFoundation                  0x22427228 0x2241e000 + 37416
    33  CoreFoundation                  0x22427014 0x2241e000 + 36884
    34  UIKit                           0x26b00c3c 0x26a7f000 + 531516
    35  UIKit                           0x26afb188 0x26a7f000 + 508296
    36  WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x0017b8ec 0x57000 + 1198316
    37  libdyld.dylib                   0x220cf872 0x220cd000 + 10354
Oct 10 18:17:45 iPad ReportCrash[995] <Error>: Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x221a42f8 0x2218e000 + 90872
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x22099d60 0x22083000 + 93536
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x22099abe 0x22083000 + 92862
Oct 10 18:17:45 iPad ReportCrash[995] <Error>: Thread 2 name:  AURemoteIO::IOThread
    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x2218e8d0 0x2218e000 + 2256
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x2218e6d4 0x2218e000 + 1748
    2   AudioToolbox                    0x249641d8 0x2483e000 + 1204696
    3   AudioToolbox                    0x24967a88 0x2483e000 + 1219208
    4   AudioToolbox                    0x248805ae 0x2483e000 + 271790
    5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2224b85a 0x22248000 + 14426
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2224b7ce 0x22248000 + 14286
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22249724 0x22248000 + 5924
Oct 10 18:17:45 iPad ReportCrash[995] <Error>: Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x221a2998 0x2218e000 + 84376
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2224adec 0x22248000 + 11756
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2224bc98 0x22248000 + 15512
    3   WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x0022340c 0x57000 + 1885196
    4   WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x00230caa 0x57000 + 1940650
    5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2224b85a 0x22248000 + 14426
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2224b7ce 0x22248000 + 14286
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22249724 0x22248000 + 5924
Oct 10 18:17:45 iPad ReportCrash[995] <Error>: Thread 4:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x221a2998 0x2218e000 + 84376
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2224adec 0x22248000 + 11756
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2224bcd8 0x22248000 + 15576
    3   WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x00223414 0x57000 + 1885204
    4   WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x00236fc6 0x57000 + 1966022
    5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2224b85a 0x22248000 + 14426
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2224b7ce 0x22248000 + 14286
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22249724 0x22248000 + 5924
Oct 10 18:17:45 iPad ReportCrash[995] <Error>: Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: NSManagedObjectContext 0x19a35da0
    Thread 5:
    0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x22242b6c 0x22241000 + 7020
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x21cbed38 0x21cac000 + 77112
    2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x21cbecc2 0x21cac000 + 76994
    3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x21cbebc4 0x21cac000 + 76740
    4   Foundation                      0x22c934e6 0x22c65000 + 189670
    5   Foundation                      0x22c9a8ec 0x22c65000 + 219372
    6   Foundation                      0x22c8b1bc 0x22c65000 + 156092
    7   Foundation                      0x22d0ea02 0x22c65000 + 694786
    8   WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x0026018a 0x57000 + 2134410
    9   WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x0025fbb8 0x57000 + 2132920
    10  CoreData                        0x240714b6 0x23fc8000 + 693430
    11  libdispatch.dylib               0x2208580e 0x22083000 + 10254
    12  libdispatch.dylib               0x2209101c 0x22083000 + 57372
    13  CoreData                        0x240713b2 0x23fc8000 + 693170
    14  WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x0025f956 0x57000 + 2132310
    15  WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x0027ffda 0x57000 + 2265050
    16  libdispatch.dylib               0x22085822 0x22083000 + 10274
    17  libdispatch.dylib               0x220945e8 0x22083000 + 71144
    18  libdispatch.dylib               0x22093fcc 0x22083000 + 69580
    19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22249b28 0x22248000 + 6952
    20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22249718 0x22248000 + 5912
Oct 10 18:17:45 iPad ReportCrash[995] <Error>: Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.uikit.backgroundTaskAssertionQueue
    Thread 6:
    0   Foundation                      0x22ccfb40 0x22c65000 + 437056
    1   AssertionServices               0x23b6a5e6 0x23b66000 + 17894
    2   AssertionServices               0x23b6a83a 0x23b66000 + 18490
    3   UIKit                           0x26d5265e 0x26a7f000 + 2963038
    4   libdispatch.dylib               0x2208580e 0x22083000 + 10254
    5   libdispatch.dylib               0x2209101c 0x22083000 + 57372
    6   UIKit                           0x26ae1a0a 0x26a7f000 + 403978
    7   UIKit                           0x26d4a5c6 0x26a7f000 + 2930118
    8   UIKit                           0x26aea94c 0x26a7f000 + 440652
    9   CoreData                        0x240a1344 0x23fc8000 + 889668
    10  CoreData                        0x23fe4568 0x23fc8000 + 116072
    11  CoreData                        0x240a017e 0x23fc8000 + 885118
    12  CoreData                        0x240a87ea 0x23fc8000 + 919530
    13  libdispatch.dylib               0x2208580e 0x22083000 + 10254
    14  libdispatch.dylib               0x2209101c 0x22083000 + 57372
    15  CoreData                        0x2409a5c0 0x23fc8000 + 861632
    16  CoreData                        0x23fe4206 0x23fc8000 + 115206
    17  CoreData                        0x240071b4 0x23fc8000 + 258484
    18  WitchesLegacy5_iPadFull         0x0025ede6 0x57000 + 2129382
    19  CoreData                        0x240714b6 0x23fc8000 + 693430
    20  libdispatch.dylib               0x22092422 0x22083000 + 62498
    21  libdispatch.dylib               0x22091a60 0x22083000 + 60000
    22  libdispatch.dylib               0x220945e8 0x22083000 + 71144
    23  libdispatch.dylib               0x22093fcc 0x22083000 + 69580
    24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22249b28 0x22248000 + 6952
    25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22249718 0x22248000 + 5912
Oct 10 18:17:45 iPad ReportCrash[995] <Error>: Thread 7:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x221a3864 0x2218e000 + 88164
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22249b34 0x22248000 + 6964
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x22249718 0x22248000 + 5912
Oct 10 18:17:45 iPad ReportCrash[995] <Error>: No thread state (register information) available
Oct 10 18:17:45 iPad ReportCrash[995] <Error>: Error Formulating Crash Report:
    Failed while requesting activity/breadcrumb diagnostics
```

Needs any help :)

Comment: It would be easier to guess if you include an actual **symbolicated** crash report.  The one clue in the console logs is "failed to scene-create in time".  It sounds as if you're doing something on the main thread that you shouldn't and therefore blocking it.

Comment: full crash logs:
https://yadi.sk/d/Ucynm0HrwQgLo
https://yadi.sk/d/9LKsUu-2wQgME
 
this is what you need, or I misunderstood?

Comment: Close.  You need to read about symbolication of crash logs so that you can turn addresses in those reports into named references that you can find in your code.

Comment: @PhillipMills Now it's right? :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I'm guessing from kVirtualAudioObjectCategoryNotSupportedError  your app uses microphone, and you might need to prompt for user to allow permission.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but there are another crash reason... I removed the error associated with kVirtualAudioObjectCategoryNotSupportedError warning.

There are ideas? I have updated the new log *^^^ there*

Comment: are you using appium?